# How to Manage Dated Exchange Rates and Currencies using Web Service Connector

Tags: java

Is it possible to update the Dated Exchange Rates and Currencies using Web Service Connector and Java? If it is, kindly give links or sample codes for references. I have searched on different sites but still cant find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app in the appexchange, that update exchanges rate from diferents sources. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000025GWyEAM

Comment: Is there a free version to this? We are currently updating our dated exchange rates manually and im trying to automate it.

Comment: €480 EUR per company per year

Comment: I'm sorry but im trying to do this cost free so it would be approved easily. I have also searched for other sites and tried to read the classes in the WSC and partner jar file and it looks like I can only access objects through the WSC. Thanks for the suggestion tho.